# Will turning garbage collection on and off frequently cause bad runtime performance?

Tags: python, performance, garbage-collection

I have a program that occasionally executes a very performance-sensitive subroutine. The program runs continuously, and the subroutine is called maybe 100 times per day. Is there any downside to calling `gc.disable()` before entering the performance-critical function, and then doing `gc.enable()` after exiting? I just want to make sure that I don't hit an "unlucky" gc in the middle of running my performance-critical function.

Comment: I would be careful with this.  `gc.disable()` by itself does not turn off CPython's reference counting.  Refcounting can get arbitrarily expensive if you drop a large object composed of many sub-objects (e.g. a huge list of objects).

Comment: gc performance is the last of your problems with a heave python code.